# Why does useEffect renders result on every page and not only on intended endpoint?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, routes, axios

I am a beginner trying to fetch data from database to the front-end using Axios, ReactJS and TypeScript. I want to the data to be rendered on localhost:3000/api/v1/getAll but the render happens on all routes. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

This is the axios request function:

```
export const getAllUsers = async (): Promise<IResponse | IErrorResponse> => {
    const axiosClient = AxiosClient.createInstance();
    try {
        const response = await axiosClient.get("/api/v1/getAll");

        return {
            success: true,
            data: response.data
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);

        return {
            success: false,
            data: isAxiosError(err) ? err.message : (err as string)
        };
    }
};
```

This is the ReactJS part:

```
const App = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState<userData[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // open browser console to see result
        const getUsers = async () => {
            const response = await getAllUsers();
            if (response.success) {
                setUsers(response.data as userData[]);
                console.log(response.data);
            } else {
                throw Error("Cannot fetch"); // temporary
            }
        };
        getUsers()
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {users && users.map(user => <li>{user.name}</li>)}
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your `useEffect` is inside the `App` component, but you will want it in a component that is on a specific route in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `useEffect` inside app component & App component is main component so it's called on every page please move your logic to separate component and add routing then i will call only on that particular route

Comment: thank you it works after I made a new component